# Installing WIF SDK 4.0

Tags: wif

I needed to install IdentityTrainingKitApril2020.VS2010, it made me install WindowsIdentityFoundation-SDK-4.0.

But setup WIF SDK fails with this message :

"Setup has detected that .NET Framework 4.0 is not installed on the system. Please choose the correct WIF SDK(3.5/4.0) installer based on the version of

the .NET Framework you intend to use."

My Machine : Windows 7 Enterprise, VS2010 Professional RTMRel Version :10.0.30319.1 . NET Version:4.0.30319 RTMRel.

I have installed : Windows6.1-KB974405-x86 (WIF Runtime)

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem. It looks like the installer doesn't have permission to check the required registry key to confirm the .NET Framework is installed. I got around the problem by running the installer from a Administrator cmd prompt:

1. Right-click cmd.exe and choose "Run as Administrator
2. CD to the appropriate directory, then execute "msiexec /i WindowsIdentityFoundation-SDK-4.0.msi"

Cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I used Orca to remove the launch condition